# react-native Modal with SafeAreaView-wrapper not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, iphone-x

We have a FilterComponent which renders a Modal, but on iPhone X it's Header is in the Statusbar.

I tried to render it with SafeAreaView but seems like this is not working:

```
return (
  <SafeAreaView>
    <Modal
      { ...defaultModalProps }
      onRequestClose={ close }
      style={ styles.container }
      visible={ visible }
    >
      <ModalNavbar close={ close }>
        Filter
      </ModalNavbar>
      <View style={ styles.content }>
        ...
      </View>
    </Modal>
  </SafeAreaView>
);
```

When FilterModal is openend on iPhoneX it still is in the Statusbar and you cant click on anything.

Any idea how to solve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Put `SafeAreaView` inside the `Modal` component

```
return (
  <Modal
    {...defaultModalProps}
    onRequestClose={close}
    style={styles.container}
    visible={visible}
  >
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "transparent" }}>
      <ModalNavbar close={close}>Filter</ModalNavbar>
      <View style={styles.content}>...</View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  </Modal>
);
```

Comment: This fixed my issue but I am confused why. Wouldn't it make more sense to have the modal inside the SafeAreaView?

Comment: @ksudu94 no, a Modal view will cover the entire screen. It is in no way bound by the size of its caller (parent)

Comment: looks like `StatusBar` will not be visible if `backgroundColor`  is not `transparent`. Am I right?

Answer (score 15):

if you use **react-native-safe-area-context** and you have a problem with modal then

```
      <Modal>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <SafeAreaView>
            
             // your modal content

          </SafeAreaView>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </Modal>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

A `Modal` fill the entire screen, so you need to provide extra spacing inside the `Modal`. Margin / Padding will not effect on Modal if applied on parent of Modal.

```
<Modal {...}>
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={closeModal}>
    <SafeAreaView {...}>
      {...}
    </SafeAreaView>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</Modal>
```